# Pointer Referring to an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Recently, I've been trying to strengthen my skills with pointers, and I ran into the following issue:

I have the following piece of code, but I run into a runtime error. I tried looking up some stuff about iterating through a pointer that represents an array, but I couldn't find anything.

Could anyone help me find the problem?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int * arr; 
    arr[0]=1; 
    arr[1]=2;
    for (int g=0; g<2; g++) cout << arr[g] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually declared any storage for the array, nor is arr actually pointing to the first element of the array (dereferencing is *undefined behavior*).

---

You are missing something like:

```
int solve[2];
int * arr = solve;
```

or

```
int solve[2];
int * arr = &solve[0];
```

Both ways will assign the address of correctly allocated storage within the scope to `arr`, and dereferencing it, is defined behavior.

Comment: So, how would I change this?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ his one is perfectly valid too

Comment: Is perfectly valid but it doesn't really make sense to add index 0... All this will do is add 0 times the length of an `int` to the adress, i.e. add zero...

Comment: imo `int *arr = &solve[0];` is clearer; it shows explicitly that you are setting your pointer to point to the first element in the array.